# Responsive background image not show up

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, responsive-images

I try to make some links in 3 columns with images and I don't know why these images dont show up. I searched a lot of information about these things ,but no one helped me. Anyone can please help me with this? :)

**HTML**

```
<div id="place">
    <div class="place_button">

            <div id="choose">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="button image1"></div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div id="choose">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="button image2"></div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div id="choose">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="button image3"></div>
                </a>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#place .place_button{
    display:table;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

#place #choose{
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
}

#place .button{
    display: table-cell;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center;
  width: 31%;
  height:auto;
    -webkit-transition:1s;-moz-transition:1s;-o-transition:1s;
}
/* There is different images! */
#place .image1{background-image: url('http://swayevents.com/sites/default/files/05_0.jpg');}
#place .image1:hover{background-image:url('https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a0401558592_16.jpg');}

#place .image2{background-image:url('http://swayevents.com/sites/default/files/05_0.jpg');}
#place .image2:hover{background-image:url('https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a0401558592_16.jpg');}

#place .image3{background-image:url('http://swayevents.com/sites/default/files/05_0.jpg');}
#place .image3:hover{background-image:url('https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a0401558592_16.jpg');}
```

There is my [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/1vo5wdzm/1/)

Answer (score 1):

setting an **image** as **`background-image`** doesn't give height and width. so you should need to add **non-percentage** value of height and width in to the **`div`** where the background image declared..

Example:

```
#place .button{ 
  width: 300px;
  height:200px;
}
```

***EDIT***

To make it responsive, you should change your column structure. Try this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="place">
  <div class="place_button">
    <a href="" id="choose" >
      <div class="button image1"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="" id="choose" >
      <div class="button image2"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="" id="choose" >
      <div class="button image3"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#place .place_button{
  display:table;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

#place #choose{
  display:block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
}

#place .button{
  background-size: cover;
  background-position:center;
  width: 300px;
  height:200px;
 -webkit-transition:1s;-moz-transition:1s;-o-transition:1s;
}
```

Comment: But what I need to do ,if I want that responsive?

Comment: can you show me what is the problem in responsive after you apply that?

Comment: images dont change the size if I change my browser sizes

Comment: thank you for the dedication, but that still doesn't work :( 
i know somethin about responsive designs. if you add non-percentage ,that doesn't make these images sizes change when I change browser sizes. That shows to all browsers that 300x200 size

Comment: i try it to your fiddle and still doesn't work? If you really want a responsive image, then declare it on a `<img>` tag not on a div a `background-image`. Is there a problem if you use `img` tag?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117795/discussion-between-daniels-jirgensons-and-jefsama).

Answer (score 0):

I found info about vh units and I try to use them and that helps me!
Now my code looks like this....

HTML *without changes*

CSS

```
#place .place_button{
    display:table;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

#place #choose{
    float: left;
    width:31%;
    margin: 1%;
}

#place .button{
    display: table-cell;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center;
    height: 40vh;
    width: 40vh;
    -webkit-transition:1s;-moz-transition:1s;-o-transition:1s;
}
```

Thanks for helping! :)